# Two classes next to each other in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navigation_desktop">

    <div class="button">1.0 Main Menu
        <div class="FadeItem">
            <ul>
                <li>1.1 Sub Menu </li>
                <li class="button">1.2 Sub Menu
                    <div class="FadeItem">
                        <ul>
                            <li>1.2.1 Sub Menu</li>
                            <li>1.2.2 Sub Menu</li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
                </li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .button {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.FadeItem {
display: none
}

.FadeItem .FadeItem {
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
top: 0;
width: 130px;
height: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

With the code above I let **FadeIn/Out** some items once I hover over a button. The code works perfectly but I have a general question regarding the coding of the **CSS** in the example above.

In the **CSS** there is this part:

```
.FadeItem .FadeItem {
}
```

When do you create a **CSS** code like this? What does it trigger?

I am a newbie to the **CSS** programming and so far I only used one class
or two classes divided by a comma. I want to improve my coding knowledge
so it would be cool if you could give me an explanation about the code above.

The code you can also find here: https://jsfiddle.net/gge42bob/3/

Comment: Take close note: Sometimes it's `.FadeItem.FadeItem` _without_ the space between. Then it's a technique to crank up the specificity of the selector, see e.g. https://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/#safely-increasing-specificity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It targets a `.FadeItem` within another `.FadeItem`, so in this case it's useful because the styles only apply to the inner `.FadeItem` element, not the outer.

Your markup is similar to

```
<div class="FadeItem">
    <div class="FadeItem"></div>
</div>
```

So only

```
.FadeItem {styles}
```

will target both of them, but

```
.FadeItem .FadeItem {styles}
```

targets **only** the one that's inside the other

Comment: It might be good to note that it's any descendent, not just direct children

Answer (score 4):

**This code:**

```
.FadeItem .FadeItem { }
```

Selects all elements with class `FadeItem` that is inside another element with class `FadeItem`.

*For example :*

```css
.FadeItem .FadeItem {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="FadeItem">First Fade Item
    <div class="FadeItem">
       Second Fade Item 
    </div>
</div>
```

**This code:**

```
.FadeItem { }
```

Selects all elements with class `FadeItem`.

*For example :*

```css
.FadeItem {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="FadeItem">First Fade Item
    <div class="FadeItem">
       Second Fade Item 
    </div>
</div>
```